# java inheritance and constructor

Tags: java

```
class A{
    int ax;int ay;

    A(int x, int y){
        ax=x;
        ay=y;
    }

 void show(){
        System.out.println("value of Ax is : "+ax+" value of Ay is : "+ay);
 }
}

class B extends A{
        int bx,by;

    B(int bx,int by){
        this.bx=bx;
        this.by=by;
    }

    void show(){
        super.show();
        System.out.println("Value of Bx is : "+bx+" value of By is : "+by);
    }
}

public class progl2q2{

    public static void main(String s\[\]){
        A m=new A(10,20);
        B b=new B(20,30);
        m.show();
        b.show();
    }
}
```

its showing error like this:

```
progl2q2.java:36: error: constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types;
        A m=new A(10,20);
            ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

C:\Users\Labuser\Desktop\saurabh\prog list2>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You having issue in your main method, please make it correct to public static void main(String args[])

Comment: @PramodYadav I think the code was copied over incorrectly/sloppily.

Comment: Are you certain that the above code is actually what you ran?

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in constructors.

In the program you have written that B extends A, and you don't have default constructor of A instead you have parametrized constructor of A, which is wrong.

When you make a variable of a class, then if that class extends some other class then its constructor initializes first, but in your case there is no way to initialize the constructor of the parent class, so the program is failing.

So, the solution is you can either have a default constructor in A class or you need to call the parametrized constructor from B.

Here is the first solution

```
class A {
    int ax;
    int ay;
    public A() {
        super();
    }
    A(int x, int y) {
        ax = x;
        ay = y;
    }
    void show() {
        System.out.println("value of Ax is : " + ax + " value of Ay is : " + ay);
    }
}
class B extends A {
    int bx, by;
    B(int bx, int by) {
        this.bx = bx;
        this.by = by;
    }
    void show() {
        super.show();
        System.out.println("Value of Bx is : " + bx + " value of By is : " + by);
    }
}
public class test {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        A m = new A(10, 20);
        B b = new B(20, 30);
        m.show();
        b.show();
    }
}
```

Here is the output:::

value of Ax is : 10 value of Ay is : 20

value of Ax is : 0 value of Ay is : 0

Value of Bx is : 20 value of By is : 30

As you can see when B object is initialized, A constructor has been called.

Here is the second solution::

```
class A {
    int ax;
    int ay;

    A(int x, int y) {
        ax = x;
        ay = y;
    }
    void show() {
        System.out.println("value of Ax is : " + ax + " value of Ay is : " + ay);
    }
}
class B extends A {
    int bx, by;

    public B(int x, int y, int bx, int by) {
        super(x, y);
        this.bx = bx;
        this.by = by;
    }

    void show() {
        super.show();
        System.out.println("Value of Bx is : " + bx + " value of By is : " + by);
    }
}
public class test {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        A m = new A(10, 20);
        B b = new B(20, 30);
        m.show();
        b.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java if you create a parametrized constructor for a class then no default constructor is created. Here you have a parameterized constructor for class A but your class B's constructor is not invoking the parametrized constructor of A but trying to call the one with no parameters which in this case does not exist.

To solve this problem you can either create a non parametrized constructor in A or simply change constructor of class B like:

```
B(int bx,int by){
  super(4,5);//or any numbers you want as parameters of A's constructor
  this.bx=bx;
  this.by=by;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined constructor in class A. Class B must invoke super() in constructor as it is extending class A. Class B should be like:

```
class B extends A {
    int bx, by;

    B(int x, int y) {
       //pass any value for super class
       //if you do not want user super() remove constructor in class A
        super(0, 1);
        this.bx = x;
        this.by = y;
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println("Value of Bx is : " + bx + " value of By is : " + by);
    }
}
```

And also fix your main method as it should be like:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
```